# Where do I find ImageMagicK manipulation description more detail in vc++?

Tags: c++, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm working on vc++ with ImageMagicK.

I'd like to apply scale and grey and something like another manipulation also too, not cli.

But, I can't find any regarding scale or grey or something like any description of manipulation ..in Magick++_tutorial.pdf.

I need any description of manipulation API functions not only above things but also another also too.

How can I find these descriptions?

Comment: You find them by looking through the web site until you find [the Magick++ documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Documentation.html).

Comment: @molbdnilo  : thanks but I need to know how to use above classes. For example, if I want to change gray space in color space,  how to use it? Or what if I want to change the image size, then what should I do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
image.quantizeColorSpace( GRAYColorspace );
```

and

```
image.resize("800x600");
```

See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html) for more details.